# Cron job to keep rails server running

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add the following line to the crontab for a rails app:

```
* * * * * lsof -i tcp | grep -v grep | grep -q puma || /home/me/app_name/bin/rails s
```

... in short, I have an error that occasionally takes down my rails server, and I would like to run this command every minute to make sure the server remains as available as possible. (The actual error is a question for another day.)

Initially, I got an error:

```
shared_helpers.rb: 34 
in 'default_gemfile': could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
```

... which traced back to line 4 in bin/rails:

```
load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
```

I changed the ('../spring') to ('./spring'), because the spring script was located in the same directory as the rails script, not in the parent. (Oddly, running `rails s` from the command line works whether I use '..' or '.' in the path.)

This, at least got rid of the error above, but now I have the following:

```
/bin/sh: 1: lsof: not found
/bin/sh: 1: grep: not found
/bin/sh: 1: grep: not found
/usr/bin/env: 'ruby_executable_hooks': No such file or directory
```

I get these errors once per minute, so at least I know the time format my entry is correct.

The relevant part of my crontab looks like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/
GEM_PATH=$GEM_PATH:/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby- 
2.4.1:/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global
* * * * * lsof -i tcp | grep -v grep | grep -q puma || /home/me/app/bin/rails s
```

I also tried:

```
* * * * * lsof -i tcp | grep -v grep | grep -q puma || /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/rails s
```

... but get the same error.

I can run `rails s` from the command line, as I mentioned. I know running the command from a logged-in shell has the benefit of login scripts being read and environment variables being set, but I don't know what I need to do to get the environment in this crontab to co-operate.

NOTE: I'm not using the `whenever` gem for this, because I'm using external commands like `grep` and `lsof`; if there is an equivalent rails-based solution (to test if the server is running, and start it if it isn't), I could do that instead of using the crontab. (But I don't know what that would be.)

Comment: This strikes me as a rather odd approach. Rather, I would expect that you would rescue the error - which would obviate the need for all of this.

Comment: I don't know what the error is. It's not showing up in the logs, and there's little to go on. It may be application-related, server-related, or something else, but until and unless I find out how to fix it, this is the best work-around I can think of. That's why I said that "[t]he actual error is a question for another day."